# PHP Illegal string offset

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem with this code :

```
echo $f[0]['id']; // result 19275
```

But after the error message is :

```
Illegal string offset 'id'
```

Why this error message? Offset 'id' exists and has a value

Comment: do a `var_dump` of your array `$f` and investigate the structure

Comment: Could you be a little clearer? Are you saying `echo $f[0]['id']` both echoes out `19275` _and_ gives you an error message? Or is there some other code in betweentwo?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you would see this error message is because $f[0] returns a string, not a sub array. A var_dump should return the proper answer to your problem. Once your question is updated with the result of that var_dump, I can help you further (print_r will also work)

For example, you could have the following structure

```
array(
    '19275'
)
```

This satisfies your requirement above, and is what you are most likely being returned.

However, you're assuming the following

```
array(
    array('id' => '19275')
)
```

You are expecting an associative array, when you are merely dealing with a simple numerically indexed array.